# Why does my C++ program crash when using a constructor?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm making a simple OpenGL program following the "learnopengl.com" tutorial. Right now the code should just show an orange triangle.

My code:

#### ScreenManager.h

```
#ifndef SCREEN_MANAGER_H
#define SCREEN_MANAGER_H

#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Input.h"
#include "Renderer.h"

class ScreenManager
{
    public:
        ScreenManager(void);
        bool isCloseRequested();
        void render();
        void update();
        void dispose();
        private:
        GLFWwindow* window;
        Renderer renderer;
};

#endif
```

#### ScreenManager.cpp

```
#include "ScreenManager.h"

ScreenManager::ScreenManager(void)
{
    // Initialize GLFW library
    glfwInit();

    // Specify the opengl version to 3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    // Specify opengl profile to core profile
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Disable resizing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    // Create the window object
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "test", nullptr, nullptr);

    // Make the GL context the active context in the thread
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Error check
    if(window==NULL){
        std::cout << "failed to create GLFW window :( " << std::endl;
        dispose();
    }

    // Make sure that GLEW use modern techniques to manage opengl functionality
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    // Initialize GLEW and check for errors
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        std::cout << "failed to initialize glew :( " << std::endl;
    }

    // Specify opengl viewport => bottom left coordinates and window size
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

    // Register the events for GLFW => currently :keyboard
    Input input(window);

    renderer.init();
}

// Check if window is closed
bool ScreenManager::isCloseRequested(){
    if(glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        return true;
    return false;
}

// Clear screen and swap buffers
void ScreenManager::render(){
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.render();

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

// Check for events (registered events)
void ScreenManager::update(){
    glfwPollEvents();
}

void ScreenManager::dispose(){
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

#### Renderer.h

```
#ifndef RENDERER_H
#define RENDERER_H

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <iostream>

class Renderer
{
    public:
        Renderer(void);
        void init();
        void render();

    private:
        void testShape();
        GLuint createVertexShader(GLuint &shader);
        GLuint createFragmentShader(GLuint &shader);
        void createShaderProgram(GLuint &program);
};

#endif
```

#### Renderer.cpp

```
#include "Renderer.h"

GLuint program;
GLuint vertexShader;
GLuint fragmentShader;
GLuint VAO;

Renderer::Renderer(){
    //init();
}

void Renderer::init(){
    testShape();

    createShaderProgram(program);
}

void Renderer::render(){
    glUseProgram(program);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Renderer::testShape(){
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3* sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(VBO, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

GLuint Renderer::createVertexShader(GLuint &shader){
    const GLchar* vertexShaderSource =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
        "void main(){\n"
        "    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
        "}";

    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    GLint success;
    GLchar info[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if(!success){
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, info);
        std::cout << "couldn't compile shader :(/n" << info << std::endl;
    }
    return vertexShader;
}

GLuint Renderer::createFragmentShader(GLuint &shader){
    const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "out vec4 color;\n"
        "void main(){\n"
        "    color = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 0);\n"
        "}";

    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    GLint success;
    GLchar info[512];
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if(!success){
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, info);
        std::cout << "couldn't compile shader :(\n" << info << "\n" << std::endl;
    }

    return fragmentShader;
}

void Renderer::createShaderProgram(GLuint &program){
    program = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(program, createVertexShader(vertexShader));
    glAttachShader(program, createFragmentShader(fragmentShader));
    glLinkProgram(program);

    GLint success;
    GLchar info[512];

    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);

    if(!success){
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 512, NULL, info);
        std::cout << "couldn't link program :(\n" << info << "\n" << std::endl;
    }

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
}
```

Well, the code works perfectly fine if I don't use the Renderer class constructor and just use the init() function, if I used the constructor instead (after uncommenting init() and commenting renderer.init()) the program crash.

The main function is in a separate class and all it does is call the ScreenManager render function in a loop.

Comment: You're going to need to show the code (e.g. main() function) that actually creates an instance of Renderer and/or calls the init() function.    Try providing the smallest complete compilable example of code possible that illustrates your problem (at present, you've included a lot of potentially distracting stuff that will distract folks trying to help). There is also no legitimate way that code can avoid using the Renderer constructor before calling init() - so your description suggests you have left out relevant information.

Comment: I got it now I was calling the Renderer constructor (in ScreenManager.h) before actually initializing opengl in the ScreenManager constructor :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `init` in the constructor, it is called during the construction of `ScreenManager`'s member, which happens before the body of `ScreenManager`'s constructor is executed.

At that point, OpenGL hasn't been initialised yet, which is why you're crashing.

Comment: oooooooooooh ,now I get it ,why didn't I think that simple :P ,thanks you helped a lot :D